# Is this true: any matrix after a random perturbation, it is diagonalizable with probability 1?

Tags: linear-algebra

As someone points out, we could change the matrix as arbitrary small as possible to make it diagnolizable,

but for any random perturbation, say $$A+E$$, E is random matrix, is the summation must be diagozable with probability 1?

Comment: Thanks, they are similar , my question is more general, say for any random perturbation... I will change the question, thanks!

Comment: wow, could you give me any reference to that? Thank you so much!

Comment: For almost every $A,B$ ($B$ inversible and not commuting with $A$ ?) if $\varepsilon$ is a continuous random variable then with a probability $1$ the characteristic polynomial $\det(A+\varepsilon B)$ won't have any double root.

Comment: Thanks, in fact it is from my research, I just need a argument to convince others in reality we do not need consider not being diagonalible, so could you give me a reference to cite? ...haha Thank you so much

Comment: Not on this site but: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12657/proving-almost-all-matrices-over-c-are-diagonalizable

Comment: see  reuns' above reply this is what I want, what is the reference for that claim, thank you all.

Comment: is there a direct reference which I could cite for this? I am not from pure math department.

Comment: is my argument reasonable, since polynomial contains no duplicate roots is is almost the whole space, a random perturbation makes no duplicate roots. My question is now how to rigorous connect this to $$det(A+\epsilon B)$$ claim the perturbation in coefficient is also random?

Comment: reasonable, any reference I could use in my paper, it is a statistics paper, just need a reference.